# Split View Controller Data parsing on the iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios4

I have following codition for my app as shown in image.

[image]

On left View : The different User selection will be done in table view.

And the selected users information will be needed on right view while pressing the button.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of Protocol is very simple to solve your problem.

When you tap on row on left side, then you just need to pass the object as userinfo and make a call to its delegate method which will be implemented in rightview.

This is very simple task if you know how to implement protocols for the viewController.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a delegate pattern.

When a row is selected from the table view in the left view, call the delegate to notify the selection. Afterward your delegate (which suppose to be the right view's controller) can display the corresponding user info.

Comment: But It may possible that user selects only one row, user can select any number of row and also can deselect it. So how to track that?

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, but you can track what are selected in an array.